# How to programmatically add a record to an APEX Interactive Grid?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I need to add a new record to one of the interactive grids on my page via javascript code.

I know how to get an record from the grid:

```
 var model = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").model;
 var record = model.getRecord(rowID);
```

But how do I add a record? Is there a function for that?

What I am trying to do is get selected rows from one grid and insert it into the underlying table in another grid. I got my javascript code to grab the records selected in grid1 and loop through them. Now I am getting the model of the grid2 and want to insert the records from grid1 into grid2

Comment: Don't use the Salesforce `apex` tag for `oracle-apex` questions.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware that `apex` was for salesforce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to insert a new record and immediately update the values.

```
var widget      = apex.region('staticIdOfIG').widget();
var grid        = widget.interactiveGrid('getViews','grid');  
var model       = grid.model; 

//insert new record on a model
var myNewRecordId = model.insertNewRecord();

//get the new record
var myNewRecord = model.getRecord(myNewRecordId);

//update record values
model.setValue(myNewRecord, 'NAME_OF_COLUMN1', 'value1');
model.setValue(myNewRecord, 'NAME_OF_COLUMN2', 'value2');
```

Example: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:8

*Click on button "INSERT ROW WITH VALUES"

```
Workspace: stackquestions
login: test
pwd: test
page: 8
```

Comment: thank you for your response. The thing is it is not exact copy of the grid row, instead it is taking some IDs and inserting them into an underlying table. Is there a method to do something like that?

Comment: I am getting "Set value not allowed for field" error

Comment: Is it an editable field? if not, this error is expected.

Comment: probably it is because it is a hidden field

Comment: try change this column to an editable type (textfield, numberfiled, etc.) and on actions menu don't show this column; you can disable edit on this item creating a dynamic action.

Comment: The event of DA is "row initialization [interactive grid]"

Comment: I made the column TextField but still getting the same error

Comment: I'm using the apex.oracle.com to test this instructions and works. login on https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550, workspace: stackquestions. user: test, pwd: test. application: stackquestions. page: 8. If you replicate this problem at this workspace, I can try help...

Comment: Nesta página eu crio um botão que insere uma nova linha no IG programaticamente. https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:8

Comment: My setup is different - I have a page with 3 grids - first two display Order data and Orderline data respectively, as a master detail page. The third grid displays all the products. I added a button on the grid toolbar to add multiple products to the order - all that check checked. So when products in the 3rd grid are checked, I need to retrieve order ID and use that, as well as some other fields from grid 3 and add it to Orderline grid.

Comment: That is were I get stuck. Orderline table has Order_Line_ID which is generated by a trigger when a record is inserted, and Order_ID, Product_ID, ITEM_PRICE, and QUANTITY fields. All 4 fields in Orderline grid I made editable

Comment: You need to find the specific line of javascript that trigger the error. These instructions works, you need to find the reason that don't work in your case. The PK column, you don't need to write in your query. remove the pk column of your select, because the values of this column is generated by the trigger.